# FLS Create for upsert

Tags: upsert, crud, fls, security-scanner

How manage FLS Create issues in Checkmarx for `upsert` statements ?

I use `isCreateable()` for `insert` and `isUpdateable()` for `update`.

But for `upsert`, I don't know what function I have to use (one or both).

Comment: I have used below solution but its still giving me the same issue. Any idea how I should make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check both `isCreateable()` and `isUpdateable()` for upsert.

Comment: If I have only one of both permissions (create or update), the AND will returns FALSE and I won't do the upsert statement !

Comment: Yes. Upsert means Update or Insert. If you want to perform an Upsert you should have create and update permission on that object. So it should be checked.

Comment: How can we check for Id field. I already check for isAccesible but still its showing the same error.

Comment: @Reshma I have used this solution but its still giving me the same issue. Any idea how I should make it work?